# Expanding an Index in a Bash Loop Script in a Combination with a Wildcard and an Underscore

Tags: bash, loops, escaping, wildcard

I have 80 pairs of files of the following type:

```
170309-N701-S517_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
170309-N701-S517_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
170309-N701-S502_S2_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
170309-N701-S502_S2_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
170309-N701-S503_S3_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
170309-N701-S503_S3_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
..
170309-N710-S507_S79_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
170309-N710-S507_S79_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
170309-N710-S508_S80_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
170309-N710-S508_S80_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

Essentially, a pair consists of the following files:

```
170309-N701-S517_S<ID>_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
170309-N701-S517_S<ID>_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

where ID varies from 1 to 80.

I would like to create 80 subfolders named S1..S80 and put each pair in the corresponding folder, e.g.

```
170309-N701-S517_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
170309-N701-S517_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

go to subfolder S1

```
170309-N701-S502_S2_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
170309-N701-S502_S2_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

go to subfolder S2

and so on.

I wrote the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..80}
do
   mkdir S$i
   mv "*_S"$i"_*" S$i
done
```

but it didn't work as expected. It created the subfolders S1..S80. However, it didn't move any of the files. It produced instead

```
mv: cannot stat `*_S1_*': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `*_S2_*': No such file or directory
```

and so on.

What am I doing wrong? Can you correct the script?

Comment: Globs don't expand in quotes, drop the quotes.

Comment: @123 Dropping the quotes is not working as expected either. It moves all the files in the first folder S1. All the remaining folders are empty.

Comment: Your underscores are causing issues with the search since they won't be inside quotes and need to be escaped. the line should `mv *\_$i\_*`

Comment: After removing the quotes, you need to surround the variable with `{}` as in `${i}` otherwise it looks for a variable named `$i_`.

Comment: @JNevill You are right - it works! If you copy-paste your comment in an answer I'll accept it. I can do it myself but I would like the credit to go to you.

Comment: @JNevill Underscores don't need to be escaped, the problem is, as ccarton mentioned, that it tries to expand `$i_`. Properly expanding the variable with `{}` is the correct solution.

Comment: Removed the underscore.js tag, which is dedicated to a JavaScript library by the same name.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I'd argue this question shouldn't be closed as a dupe. Sure, the answer here resembles the one found in the link, but the question doesn't, and so per [standard SO guidelines](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication) isn't a dupe. This question's greatest sin, as far as I can see, is that the title is much too unspecific.

Comment: @AkselA You are right about the title - I changed it to add more specifics.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You marking up the question as a duplicate prevents me from entering another answer. Namely, that JNevill's suggestion worked. Not sure why but it did. And JNevill's post is a lot less verbose than the current answer.

Comment: @Nick, it works because quoting the `*`s makes them literal, not glob characters. That said, it's only valid with characters that don't exist in IFS -- if you were running with an environment with, say, `IFS=0`, you'd have bugs with JNevill's aswer too. And you can't use it with all possible values of the `$i` variable -- if you had a value with spaces, again, buggy (with a *default* IFS value, this time). Or a value that would make your expansion parse as a glob (with at least one matching file in default settings, but without that caveat if `nullglob` or `failglob` flags are enabled).

Comment: @Nick, ...so, the more robust thing is `mv *_"$i"_*` -- that way the expansion is properly quoted, whereas the asterisks are properly unquoted.

Comment: @AkselA, I disagree that the linked SO blog post supports your point. The question doesn't resemble what's in the link only because it contains content extraneous to its underlying problem and hasn't been properly simplified to a [mcve]. The **only** distinguishing factor between the two is a presence of the wildcard in the same expansion -- if the question were [edit]ed to draw out and lean on that difference (while removing the irrelevancies that obscure it), *then* I'd agree it should be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do with the `mv "*_S"$i"_*" S$i` line is called [variable expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html), and if you as a part of that expansion wants to concatenate the variable with other characters, you need to let BASH know what is a variable and what is a plain character. You do this by enclosing the variable name in curly braces. E.g:

```
var=FOO
echo "BAR ${var} BAZ"
# BAR FOO BAZ
```

In the case of your loop:

```
touch \
  170309-N701-S517_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz\
  170309-N701-S517_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz\
  170309-N701-S502_S2_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz\
  170309-N701-S502_S2_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz\
  170309-N701-S503_S3_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz\
  170309-N701-S503_S3_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz

for i in {1..80}
do
if test -n "$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*_S${i}_*" -print -quit)"
then
   mkdir "S${i}"
   mv *"_S${i}_"* "S$i"
fi
done
```

That if-then-fi bit is there just to avoid making directories for non-existing files. Entirely optional.

Also note that globbing character `*` must be used *unquoted* in order to work with `mv`, because inside `"..."` or `'...'`, `*` is treated as a *literal*.
An exception to this is however seen in the `find` command, where the content between the double quotes will be expanded as it is passed on to `find`. To avoid expansion in this case the argument can be enclosed in *single* quotes (`'...'`)

Comment: To be clear -- this is necessary if and only if the immediately following characters are -- like the underscore -- valid in a shell variable name.

Comment: `find` is a bit expensive performance-wise, and means you're using two different glob mechanisms (`find`'s there, and the shell's a few lines later for the `mv` -- if you have shell extglobs enabled, and a more interesting glob expression, they may not match). I'd suggest `matches=( *_S"$i"_* ); if [[ -e ${matches[0]} || -L ${matches[0]} ]]; then ...` to avoid external-command startup cost, and to ensure that you can then `mv "${matches[@]}" "S$i"` later, reusing the result of your single glob operation rather than recomputing it..

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: If I was writing this routine from scratch it would look rather different. What I posted was a minimal effort improvement.

Comment: In defense of perfectionism -- we're building an educational resource here; an answer has life well beyond when the OP it was first written for is done with it.